# Should I go into work when I didn't get enough sleep?

Tags: health

I've been fighting a cold and took a couple days off from work. I started feeling better yesterday evening, but I couldn't fall asleep until about 4 hours before I needed to wake up.

I work as a programmer. I think I'm physically capable of going into work, but I'll be pretty checked out, and getting some more sleep will both make it easier for me to focus and help me knock out my cold.

In situations like these, is it reasonable to call in sick for the day or for part of the day? How do I decide where to draw the line?

Comment: I decided to go into work today, but I'd still appreciate some advice on how to decide on this situation in the future!

Comment: Does your company have a flexible working hours policy?

Comment: Opinion based I assume?

Comment: @Downvoters: I know you can't tell me whether to take a particular day off. I'm skiing for advice on how to decide, not for you to tell me what to do. In my question, I specifically ask, "How do I decide where to draw the line?"

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors: company, culture, team, legal framework, how well you're perceived, your attendance, ... I'm not sure it's answerable even if you're just asking about what to consider.

Comment: It's some trade-off between how well you're feeling, how well you think you can perform, how common this is, how many days you've taken off recently, how many days you can still take off, how often you take days off, how much this will affect how you feel the next day and how things are going at work i.t.o deadlines and performance.

Comment: All those factors, plus a healthy dose of company policy. Some employers have specific sick days, others have a general "PTO" bucket with specific rules on how and when it can be used. I've even had employers that had a specific bucket of "wellness" days for occasions like this - you're not explicitly sick (ie a doctor would probably not write a diagnosis) but you feel off and aren't sure if you're able to perform your job.

Comment: This reminds me of a video I saw recently.  Retired Navy Seal Jocko Willink has your answer:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Vp7fTgQ3g

Answer (score 5):

Do you have employer-provided sick days? This is what those are for.

Can you work remotely and still get your tasks completed as expected?

No one can teach you common sense. If missing a day of work due to lack of sleep and mild illness would cause major problems then don't take a sick day. Otherwise be kind to yourself, take the time off appropriate to your needs and communicate that to the proper internal folks in a timely manner.

Comment: *No one can teach you common sense* -- **this**.